# RestKit: Values to BOOL

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have an `NS_ENUM` that holds the status of a checklist. The two properties are `Pending` and `Completed`.

`typedef NS_ENUM (NSUInteger, ChecklistStatus) { Pending, Completed };`

I am trying to take the status and map that to a true/false value. The method i'm doing this with is via RKValueTransformer.

Here is the code for that:

```
+(RKValueTransformer *)checklistStatusToBooleanTransformer
{
    RKValueTransformer *transformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class sourceClass, __unsafe_unretained Class destinationClass) {
        return ([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]]);
    } transformationBlock:^BOOL(NSNumber *inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, __unsafe_unretained Class outputClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        // validate the input
        RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, [NSNumber class], error);
        if([inputValue isEqual:@(Completed)]) {
            *outputValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        } else {
            *outputValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }

        return YES;
    }];

    return transformer;
}
```

I'm not able to explicitly cast my output value as a BOOL, so i'm really lost as to what I should do here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you need a `BOOL` value? The posted code looks correct (other than one of the `YES` values should probably be a `NO` value.

Comment: I need to map `Pending` to `false` and `Completed` to `true`, so `outputValue` should be of type bool. the current code returns a number of 0 or 1, which isn't what I need

Comment: You can only convert to an object type. Wrapping the `BOOL` values in `NSNumber` is your only option.

Comment: So it's not possible to output a `True`/`false` value?

Comment: Not directly through the transformer, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't explicitly convert, since `BOOL` isn't a primitive type. Check if the desired output is a string "false"/"true" instead of actualy values of t/f